# Multi line input from stdin using fgets()

Tags: c, string, malloc, file-handling, fgets

I am trying to input something like this

```
line 1
this is line 2
now line 3
```

Using fgets and from the user stdin

My snippet:

```
char *line;

while ((line = fgets(text, BUF_SIZE, stdin)) != NULL) {

//save and process line
```

However, upon runnnig this I am stuck at stdin until I do Ctrl+C force quit.

How do I check the 2-enter key aka '\n' using this? so that the code can proceed to the next lines following the 'read from stdin section'

I am open to using getc or getline() if that is a simpler solution.

Comment: `getline()` is useful when available, yet it is not in the standard C library.

Comment: Post definition of `text`.  A [mcve] is even better.

Answer (score 1):

fgets returns NULL when it hits the end of file marker aka EOF. However, unlike a standard text file, stdin doesn't automatically encounter the EOF marker since there is no pre-designated end of file location that will be automatically run into like a standard text file. If you want to send the end of file marker to stdin, you have to type in a command unique to each operating system. For example, on windows you enter Crtl-Z to send EOF to stdin. Anytime you are stuck on something like this, try to look up the documentation of the function you're using (in this case fgets).

Also, there's no need to save the return value of fgets into "line". You can just compare the return value of the function directly to NULL like

```
while (fgets(text, BUF_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
// do stuff
}
```

Comment: Would you say using getline() will be simpler? What would be the EOF check for that? @Ben

Comment: *there is no "end of file" since it's not a file* – it IS a file. `stdin` is defined as `extern FILE *stdin`.

Comment: I am aware of that and agree with you Rohan. But I'm inferring this person is a beginner in C so I was just trying to explain it in words they could better understand. What I really meant was stdin is not like reading from a text file where it will automatically hit EOF at the end. With stdin, you haven to manually enter it. And for a beginners purposes, you don't think about stdin as being a file even though it is defined that way. Once again, I was just trying to explain it in a beginner friendly way without getting bogged down in official definitions.

Comment: However, to avoid confusion, I will slightly reword my original answer.

Comment: @ankitrana_ I wouldn't say one is simpler than the other they're just different. And in regards to the EOF check, just look up the documentation of getline and compare it to the documentation of fgets to see how they differ. I won't say it here since being able to look up documentation yourself to figure things out is a skill every programmer needs and I want you to practice. However, if you're still confused, just comment back.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize scanf("%[^\n]s", buf); was considered bad. I'll remove it.

Comment: @chux I thought it was a modified version of ```scanf("%s", but)``` so you still need to include the s. I take your word for it, and I've looked it up and seen you're right. I've just used it before in my classes and it worked so I didn't know it was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for '\n' and break while loop
your while loop should look something like this

```
while ((line = fgets(text, 100, stdin)) != NULL) {  
    if(text[0] == '\n'){
            break;
        }
       /* do your work here */
}
```